# NEventStore get projection which lists all aggregates of a given type

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

I am using the [IRepository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Domain/master/src/NEventStore.Domain/Persistence/IRepository.cs) interface from the [NEventStore.Domain project](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Domain). 
I would like to create a projection that is a list of all the aggregates of the given aggregate type. How would I go about doing this:

So if I have a `ReportBatch` aggregate, I am looking to list all the report batches I have saved. How can I accomplish this? Am I barking up the wrong tree with projections? Should I just be saving to a ReportBatchList aggregate when I get `Created` events for the `ReportBatch`.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just be saving to a ReportBatchList aggregate when I get
>   Created events for the ReportBatch.

No.  You should have a projection that writes to a read model each time it receives a Created event.  You would then query this read model to get the list.  The read model could be a database (SQL or NoSQL), an in-memory construct, a text file, etc.

Note that it will **not** be "a list of all the aggregates of the given aggregate type".  It's a read model, and while a read model may have knowledge of data that is generated by an aggregate, it does not directly represent an aggregate.

Event Sourcing is an advanced form of Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS), in which writes (aggregates et al) and reads (projections and read models) are conceptually completely separate.

Comment: +1 with the mention that ES (as a concept) is unrelated to CQRS, however they are pretty much always used together